# Regexp to insert string in the beginning of anchor tag?

Tags: php, html, regex

I need to insert a string directly after the open anchor ends (where the anchor content starts).

**Here is my code:**

```
<ul id="menu-topmenu2" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-5">
        <a href="http://localhost/domain/barnlager.se/?page_id=2">
            About
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-5">
        <a href="http://localhost/domain/barnlager.se/?page_id=2">
            Services
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In this example I need content before "About" and "Services". A short regexp should do it? The HTML code above can be a string called $content.

I use PHP. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you tag it with javascript?

Comment: Removed js tag. There isn't any javascript involved here. Also, you're about to get about 50 answers telling you not to parse HTML with Regexp. Some may even explain why. They're all going to be right, btw - you shouldn't use Regexp to parse HTML **unless** you only ever have a specific locked down subset of HTML files you will be parsing.

Comment: How would you solve it then Stephen? Sorry about the Javascript tag, someone removed it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use parser, DOM for instance:

```
$content = '...your html string...';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<html><body>'.$content.'</body></html>');
$x = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($x->query('//a') as $anchor){
    // strrev(trim($anchor->nodeValue))) is just an example. put anything you like.
    $anchor->insertBefore(new DOMText(strrev(trim($anchor->nodeValue))),$anchor->firstChild);
}
echo $doc->saveXML($doc->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0));
```

And as an added bonus it throws a warning you have defined `id="menu-item-5"` twice in your HTML, which is not valid.

Comment: Almost as I coded it. Yours might be even better?

     $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML($content);
    $xpath = new DomXPath($dom); 
    $tag = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
 $counter = $tag->length;
 for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) {
  $result = $tag->item($i)->nodeValue;
  $content = str_replace($result, '<img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=seo.getupdated.se&alt=feed" />'.$result, $content);
 }

Comment: The `getElementsByTagName` could actually be faster and eliminate the need for `DOMXPath` altogether. I would not try to use a `str_replace` on the original content however: firstly, `DOMDocument` has a knack of translating entities, secondly: it is by no means guaranteed that your `$result` doesn't literally appear somewhere else, resulting in improper replacements. If you already have the stuff in `DOM`, just add an DOMElement with the DOM functions at the proper location.

Comment: You have missed a ) in the foreach. Fix it and I'll put a green check on this post.

I rekommend this problem by the way:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660962/xpath-insert-before-and-after-with-dom-and-php

Comment: Talk about blast from the past, but there you go, syntax fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can find every anchor tag with `/<a.*?>/i`. If you want to replace something after that, the call would look like `preg_replace("/(<a.*?>)/", '$1YOUR ADDITIONAL TEXT', $content)`.

If for whatever reason you need a double-quoted string as the replacement argument, make sure to backslash-escape the `$1`.