# xPath insert before and after - With DOM and PHP

Tags: php, dom

**I need to add a class to a HTML structure.**

My class is called "*container*" and should start right after **<div><ul><li></h4>** (the child of ul and its simblings, not grandchilds) and should end right before the closing  of the same element.

**My whole code looks like this:**

```
<?php
$content = '
    <div class="sidebar-1">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <ul> 
                    <li><a href="http://www.test.com">Test</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="http://www.test.com">Test</a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </li> 
            <li>
                <p>Paragraf</p>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <h4>New title</h4>
                <ul> 
                    <li>Some text</li>
                    <li>Some text åäö</li>
                </ul> 
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$x = new DOMXPath($doc);

$start_text = '<div class="container">';
$end_text = '</div>';

foreach($x->query('//div/ul/li') as $anchor)
{
    $anchor->insertBefore(new DOMText($start_text),$anchor->firstChild);
}
echo $doc->saveXML($doc->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0));
?>
```

It works as far as i can add the class opening but not the closing element. I also get strange encoding doing this. I want the output to be the same encoding as the input.

**The result should be**

```
    <div class="sidebar-1">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <div class="content">
                    <ul> 
                        <li><a href="http://www.test.com">Test</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="http://www.test.com">Test</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <div class="content">
                    <p>Paragraf</p>
                </div>
            </li> 
            <li>
                <h4>New title</h4>
                <div class="content">
                    <ul> 
                        <li>Some text</li>
                        <li>Some text åäö</li>
                    </ul> 
                </div>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have a conceptual error here. You want to embbed all `ul`'s children into a `div` element and make this `div` the only child of `ul`

Comment: No, I want to add the div-element within the li-element. I added the result HTML to my post.

Comment: This is *not* an XPath question.

Comment: The correct answer uses DOMXPath, so yes, this is a XPath question.

Comment: It doesn't matter what selector it uses: `appendChild` and `removeChild` DOM API methods are the key in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a more elegant way to reassign all children, so I guess this will do. I think it gets what you're after, though.

*(NOTE: Code updated to reflect additional requirements in the comments.)*

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$x = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($x->query('//div/ul/li') as $anchor)
{
    $container = $doc->importNode(new DOMElement('div'));
    $container->setAttribute('class', 'container');

    $next = $anchor->firstChild;
    while ($next !== NULL) {
        $curr = $next;
        $next = $curr->nextSibling;

        if (($curr->nodeName != 'h4')
            || ($curr->attributes === NULL)
            || ($curr->attributes->getNamedItem('class') === NULL)
            || !preg_match('#(^| )title( |$)#', $curr->attributes->getNamedItem('class')->nodeValue)
        ) {
            $container->appendChild($anchor->removeChild($curr));
        }
    }

    $anchor->appendChild($container);
}
```

As for character encoding, I've been messing with it for a while and it's a tricky issue. The characters display correctly when you load with `loadXML()` but not with `loadHTML()`. There's [a workaround in the comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251), but it ain't pretty. Hopefully some of the user comments will help you can find a usable solution.

Comment: Great answer, BUT I was a little too quick to post how the HTML result should be. One detail was wrong.

Instead of having "container"-class start right after /li it should start right after /h4. (I edited my post)

The ending /div is correct like it is in your code.

Big / small thing to fix? Sorry for this. Gave you 1 vote up so far.

Comment: No problem. Code updated, though it assumes that there will only be one `h4`. If multiple `h4`s, they'll all be excluded from the container and piled at the top, since the container `div` is appended last. Note that I traversed the children like a linked list. You can't simply iterate over `$anchor->childNodes` because you'd be changing the nodes while you iterate, causing all sorts of confusing behavior.

Comment: It seems to work as expected. The thing about multiple h4 problem. Would it be possible to solve it by adding a "title"-class to the h4 that is going to be piled? That way the title h4 will be unique compared to the other h4 tags. My guess is that the only thing that needs to change is the if statement?

Comment: Yep, you can do it that way. See updated code. It must check as you delve deeper to make sure the object you're about to operate on actually exists, to prevent errors. Also, note that the regular expression checks merely for the existence of the "title" class (at beginning, middle, or end), since elements are allowed to have multiple classes separated by spaces.

Comment: More complicated if statement than I thought it would be, but it seems to work. I've tested it with a few scenarios and no bugs found so far. Great thanks for all your help!

Comment: Glad to help. :-) Since it grew to this, I considered writing a separate function for all those checks relating to the class so the `if` wouldn't be as complicated. Just do that instead if you feel it looks cleaner or easier to understand.